# Lookup values do not display in gridview

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have an Employee list that has 2 lookup columns(Department and Manager). The below code works fine to display the employee list as a gridview, but the issue is that the these 2 lookup columns display Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FieldLookUp in place of the actual values.

I need to display the actual values in the grid, as seen in the sharepoint list.

Kindly help.
Thanks.

The following is the code using CSOM

```
List oList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Employees");
        clientContext.Load(oList);

        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><RowLimit>3</RowLimit></View>";

        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection itemInfo = oList.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(itemInfo);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


dt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn col = new DataColumn();
        col = new DataColumn("col1");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        col = new DataColumn("col2");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        col = new DataColumn("col3");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        col = new DataColumn("col4");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        col = new DataColumn("col5");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        col = new DataColumn("col6");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        col = new DataColumn("col7");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        col = new DataColumn("col8");
        dt.Columns.Add(col);
        foreach (var list in itemInfo)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["col1"] = list["Title"];
            dr["col2"] = list["Last_x0020_Name"];
            dr["col3"] = list["u5ib"];
            dr["col4"] = list["Address"];
            dr["col5"] = list["Department"];
            dr["col6"] = list["Manager"];
            dr["col7"] = list["Gender"];
            dr["col8"] = list["Salary"];
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
```

The following is the code for Grid

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gridview" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="col1" HeaderText="First Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="col2" HeaderText="Last Name" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="col3" HeaderText="Age" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="col4" HeaderText="Address" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="col5" HeaderText="Department" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="col6" HeaderText="Manager" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="col7" HeaderText="Gender" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="col8" HeaderText="Salary" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a better solution :

```
            //Department column
            FieldLookupValue deptItem = new FieldLookupValue();
            deptItem.LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListDepartment.SelectedValue);
            myItem["Department"] = deptItem;
            myItem.Update();

            //Manager column
            FieldLookupValue managerItem = new FieldLookupValue();
            managerItem.LookupId = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownListManager.SelectedValue);
            myItem["Manager"] = managerItem;
            myItem.Update();
```

Answer (score 1):

For lookup columns we should get values like as bellow:

```
// Manger column
    FieldLookupValue lookup = list["Manager"] as FieldLookupValue;
     dr["col6"] = lookup.LookupValue; // for display value; Use lookup.LookupId for lookup ID

// Department column
    FieldLookupValue lookup = list["Department"] as FieldLookupValue;
     dr["col5"] = lookup.LookupValue;
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Also could you tell how to insert values into a list that contains loopup columns? @Nagababu

Answer (score 0):

For lookup columns we should set values like as bellow:

```
//Department column
 FieldLookupValue lv = new FieldLookupValue();
 lv.LookupId = 1; // here instead of 1, you should provide corresponding Department list item ID
 item["col5"] = lv;
 item.Update();
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Adding the following lines worked 
myItem["Department"] = 1;
myItem["Manager"] = 1;
I also had to set the parent list as ID (earlier it was only title)